# Laplace Transform $f(t)=2\cos(3t)$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

Determine the laplace transform of the function $f(t)=2\cos(3t)$, without using the table of Laplace transforms.

I use by part integration to solve it, with $u=e^{-st},\, du/dt=-se^{-st}$ and $v=\frac{2}{3}\sin(3t)$. I get $0$ at the end since $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} e^{-st}$ and $-se^{-st}$ is $0$. However, the graphic calculator shows the answer is $1/5$.

So how to solve this question?

Answer (score 1):

We do integration by parts twice and arrive at:

$$\begin{align} \mathscr{L} (2 \cos(3t)) & = \int_0^{\infty} ~ 2 \cos(3 t) e^{-s t}~dt \\ \\ &= \dfrac{e^{-s t}( 6 \sin(3 t) - 2 s \cos(3 t))}{s^2 + 9}~\Bigr|_{t=0}^{t = \infty} \\ \\ &= \dfrac{2s}{s^2+9}\end{align}$$

An alternate approach is to utilizes Euler's formula.

Comment: i find out my mistake now, thanks a lot! =)

Comment: You are welcome. Please recall to upvote and/or accept answers that are helpful. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
$$\mathcal{L}[a\cos bx](s)=a\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\cos(bx)\mathrm dx$$
Then recall that $\cos x=\text{Re}\,e^{ix}$. Hence we have
$$\mathcal{L}[a\cos bx](s)=a\,\text{Re}\int_0^\infty e^{-(s-ib)x}\mathrm dx$$
Which is 
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}[a\cos bx](s)&=a\,\text{Re}\,\frac1{s-ib}\\
&=a\,\text{Re}\,\frac{s+ib}{s^2+b^2}\\
&=\frac{as}{s^2+b^2}
\end{align}$$
Your case is of course given by $a=2$ and $b=3$.